# Flask: current_user becomes anonymous outside of route

Tags: python, authentication, flask

Have had a look at similar questions but haven't found one that explains why the current_user value is wiped after my login function runs.

My login route:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
        flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

My registration & login forms

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
  username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
  email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
  password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
  confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
  submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):

  email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
  password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
  remember = BooleanField('Remember Me')
  submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

Using pbd I can see that once I have logged in, current_user is set to my login details, but once I am returned to the homepage, it returns to - AnonymousUserMixin.

This means my

```
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

does not get triggered when clicking to the home or login page.

I am following the Corey Schafer flask guide, specifically lesson 6:
https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/tree/master/Python/Flask_Blog/06-Login-Auth

The full repo for my code is available here:
https://github.com/gog99/Flaskblog

Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: is the result same, if you use `@login_required` decorator from `Flask-Login` on designated page?

Comment: I added @ login_required to my test route. After logging in and going to /random, I recieve a 401 unauthorised error. Thank you for the suggestion though I need to complete more tests like this

Comment: My best bet would be that your `load_user(user_id)` is not returning user correctly. Check whether it returns user object or None, and what is the user_id that is passed to it.

Comment: I haven't added any load_user code yet as it seems to become relevant when using the login manager

Comment: Just realised I do in my models.py file- will follow it from there

Answer (score 0):

@Blomex was correct, cannot believe this had me stuck for so long-

In models.py,

Old:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

New:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```